# IBM Worklight push notification not showing after authentication

Tags: push-notification, ibm-mobilefirst, google-cloud-messaging

Hi I have a very strange Push Notification issue. I tried with the provided PushNotification project and everything worked fine for me. But now in my app when I tried to implement it in a similar manner I got this issue.
So what I have done is in my main.js file I have added the following code for the user to be able to subscribe.

```
if (WL.Client.Push){

    WL.Client.Push.onReadyToSubscribe = function(){
        alert("onReadyToSubscribe");

            alert("You said yes");
            WL.Client.Push.registerEventSourceCallback(
                    "myPush1", 
                    "PushAdapter", 
                    "PushEventSource1", 
                    pushNotificationReceived);
            if(!WL.Client.Push.isSubscribed("myPush1"))
                {
                    if(confirm('Do you allow CSOL to send notification to you?')) {
                        WL.Client.Push.subscribe("myPush1", {
                            onSuccess: doSubscribeSuccess,
                            onFailure: doSubscribeFailure
                        });
                }
                }
            else
                {
                alert(WL.Client.Push.isSubscribed("myPush1"));
                }





    };

}
```

PushAdapter-impl.js

```
 /*
    *  Licensed Materials - Property of IBM
    *  5725-G92 (C) Copyright IBM Corp. 2006, 2013. All Rights Reserved.
    *  US Government Users Restricted Rights - Use, duplication or
    *  disclosure restricted by GSA ADP Schedule Contract with IBM Corp.
    */

    WL.Server.createEventSource({
        name: 'PushEventSource1',
        onDeviceSubscribe: 'deviceSubscribeFunc',
        onDeviceUnsubscribe: 'deviceUnsubscribeFunc',
        securityTest:'PushApplication-strong-mobile-securityTest'
    });

    function deviceSubscribeFunc(userSubscription, deviceSubscription){
        WL.Logger.debug(">> deviceSubscribeFunc");
        WL.Logger.debug(userSubscription);
        WL.Logger.debug(deviceSubscription);
    }

    function deviceUnsubscribeFunc(userSubscription, deviceSubscription){
        WL.Logger.debug(">> deviceUnsubscribeFunc");
        WL.Logger.debug(userSubscription);
        WL.Logger.debug(deviceSubscription);
    }

    function javaCheck(requestID, oldStatus, newStatus){
         return {
                result : com.ibm.mycsol.pushdemo.push(requestID, oldStatus, newStatus)
            };
    }

    function submitNotification(userId, notificationText){
        //userId = WL.Server.getActiveUser()
        var userSubscription = WL.Server.getUserNotificationSubscription('PushAdapter.PushEventSource1', userId);

        if (userSubscription==null){
            return { result: "No subscription found for user :: " + userId };
        }

        var badgeDigit = 1;

        var notification = WL.Server.createDefaultNotification(notificationText, 1, {userId:userId});

        WL.Logger.debug("submitNotification >> userId :: " + userId + ", text :: " + notificationText);

        //WL.Server.notifyAllDevices(userSubscription, notification);
        WL.Server.notifyAllDevices(userSubscription, notification);

        return { 
            result: "Notification sent to user :: " + userId 
        };
    }
```

Everything works fine when I have the app in the foreground. Or when I have pressed the home button on my phone I receive the notification and clicking on the notification reopens the app and shows the specific notification. But when I press the backbutton or I logout I receive the notification, clicking on the notification takes me back to the app and asks me for login. But once I login I am not able to see the notification. 
I am using a custom login module which checks the username password against a hardcoded string value. 
Here is the log

```
02-27 11:50:21.981: V/WebViewInputDispatcher(30541): blockWebkitDraw
02-27 11:50:21.981: V/WebViewInputDispatcher(30541): blockWebkitDraw lockedfalse
02-27 11:50:22.286: D/webview(30541): blockWebkitViewMessage= false
02-27 11:50:22.336: D/myCSOLApp(30541): Request [login]
02-27 11:50:22.351: D/ProgressBar(30541): setProgress = 0
02-27 11:50:22.351: D/ProgressBar(30541): setProgress = 0, fromUser = false
02-27 11:50:22.351: D/ProgressBar(30541): mProgress = 0mIndeterminate = false, mMin = 0, mMax = 10000
02-27 11:50:22.381: D/dalvikvm(30541): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 277K, 20% free 10773K/13392K, paused 11ms, total 11ms
02-27 11:50:22.411: D/dalvikvm(30541): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 376K, 19% free 10877K/13392K, paused 10ms, total 10ms
02-27 11:50:22.426: D/WebView(30541): onSizeChanged - w:320 h:547
02-27 11:50:22.481: D/ProgressBar(30541): updateDrawableBounds: left = 0
02-27 11:50:22.481: D/ProgressBar(30541): updateDrawableBounds: top = 0
02-27 11:50:22.481: D/ProgressBar(30541): updateDrawableBounds: right = 48
02-27 11:50:22.481: D/ProgressBar(30541): updateDrawableBounds: bottom = 48
02-27 11:50:22.556: D/myCSOLApp(30541): Request [http://9.127.62.227:10080/MYCSOL/apps/services/api/myCSOLApp/android/query]
02-27 11:50:22.621: D/myCSOLApp(30541): Request [http://9.127.62.227:10080/MYCSOL/apps/services/api/myCSOLApp/android/query]
02-27 11:50:22.756: D/ProgressBar(30541): setProgress = 0
02-27 11:50:22.756: D/ProgressBar(30541): setProgress = 0, fromUser = false
02-27 11:50:22.756: D/ProgressBar(30541): mProgress = 0mIndeterminate = false, mMin = 0, mMax = 10000
02-27 11:50:22.761: D/myCSOLApp(30541): Request [http://9.127.62.227:10080/MYCSOL/apps/services/api/myCSOLApp/android/query]
02-27 11:50:22.806: D/ProgressBar(30541): updateDrawableBounds: left = 0
02-27 11:50:22.806: D/ProgressBar(30541): updateDrawableBounds: top = 0
02-27 11:50:22.806: D/ProgressBar(30541): updateDrawableBounds: right = 48
02-27 11:50:22.806: D/ProgressBar(30541): updateDrawableBounds: bottom = 48
02-27 11:50:22.846: E/ViewRootImpl(30541): sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
02-27 11:50:30.956: D/myCSOLApp(30541): Clearing notification subscriptions.
02-27 11:50:30.956: D/myCSOLApp(30541): Updating notification subscriptions.
02-27 11:50:30.961: D/WLDroidGap(30541): unregisterReceivers:Receiver not registered: null
02-27 11:50:30.961: D/WLDroidGap(30541): unregisterReceivers:Receiver not registered: null
02-27 11:50:30.966: D/WLDroidGap(30541): Activity started from message notification
02-27 11:50:30.966: D/WLDroidGap(30541): Queuing message for dispatch to javascript
02-27 11:50:30.966: D/WLDroidGap(30541): dispatchPending called. Number of pending messages: 1
02-27 11:50:30.966: W/ResourceType(30541): No package identifier when getting name for resource number 0x00000064
02-27 11:50:30.966: D/WLDroidGap(30541): dispatchPending webView=com.worklight.androidgap.WLWebView{4285e1d8 VFEDH.CL .F....I. 0,0-320,547 #64} messageCallback=null
02-27 11:50:30.966: D/WLDroidGap(30541): dispatchPending called. Number of pending messages: 1
02-27 11:50:30.966: W/ResourceType(30541): No package identifier when getting name for resource number 0x00000064
02-27 11:50:30.966: D/WLDroidGap(30541): dispatchPending webView=com.worklight.androidgap.WLWebView{4285e1d8 VFEDH.CL .F....I. 0,0-320,547 #64} messageCallback=null
02-27 11:50:30.966: V/GCMRegistrar(30541): Registering receiver
02-27 11:50:30.966: D/GCMRegistrar(30541): resetting backoff for com.myCSOLApp
02-27 11:50:30.971: V/GCMRegistrar(30541): Registering app com.myCSOLApp of senders 774173770625
02-27 11:50:30.986: D/myCSOLApp(30541): response [http://9.127.62.227:10080/MYCSOL/apps/services/api/myCSOLApp/android/query] success: /*-secure-
02-27 11:50:30.986: D/myCSOLApp(30541): {"totalTime":8024,"isSuccessful":true,"requests":[{"isFav":"N","comments":[{"SEQNO":"1122","USERNAME":"EDGAR2 CAMARENA2テスト","COMMENTTYPE":"BP","REQUESTCOMMENT_ID":"20879","REQUESTID":"GASUK1402261122","COMMENTTEXT":"sdfdsf","UPDTIMESTAMP":"2014-02-26 13:52:59.684675","ANSWER":"","UPDUSERID":"ecamaren@mx1.ibm.com"}],"REQTYPE":"Create new maintenance proposal","REQUESTID":"GASUK1402261122","TYPE":"TSSP","WWW_STATUS":"Submitted","UPDTIMESTAMP":""},{"isFav":"N","comments":[{"SEQNO":"1121","USERNAME":"EDGAR2 CAMARENA2テスト","COMMENTTYPE":"BP","REQUESTCOMMENT_ID":"20878","REQUESTID":"GASUK1402261121","COMMENTTEXT":"sdfsdf","UPDTIMESTAMP":"2014-02-26 13:08:41.661944","ANSWER":"","UPDUSERID":"ecamaren@mx1.ibm.com"}],"REQTYPE":"Create new maintenance proposal","REQUESTID":"GASUK1402261121","TYPE":"TSSP","WWW_STATUS":"Submitted","UPDTIMESTAMP":""}],"stat":"ok","responseHeaders":{"Server":"WebSphere Application Server\/8.5","X-Powered-By":"Servlet\/3.0","Transfer-Encoding":"chunked","Content-Language":"en-US","Content-Type":"application\/json","Date":"Thu, 27 Feb 2014 03:50:32 GMT"},"WL-Authentication-Success":{"wl_deviceNoProvisioningRealm":{"userId":"0afa2eb3-708a-3b1e-a2cf-79f4afe26820","attributes":{"mobileClientData":"com.worklight.core.auth.ext.MobileClientData@2db9f248"},"isUserAuthenticated":1,"displayName":"0afa2eb3-708a-3b1e-a2cf-79f4afe26820"},"wl_antiXSRFRealm":{"userId":"hq7l1qekklblb3lfa2no754oc6","attributes":{},"isUserAuthenticated":1,"displayName":"hq7l1qekklblb3lfa2no754oc6"},"wl_remoteDisableRealm":{"userId":"null","attributes":{},"isUserAuthenticated":1,"displayName":"null"},"CustomAuthenticatorRealm":{"userId":"ecamaren@mx1.ibm.com","attributes":{"AuthenticationDate":"Thu Feb 27 11:50:24 SGT 2014","userIdentity":null},"isUserAuthenticated":1,"displayName":null}},"statusReason":"OK","notificationSubscriptionState":{"token":"APA91bGYP18rdbg_25Ginyts3qGmCPDMqLV4AEQARVEFSARyKyGexuKFIhuloZbg0tWzzq_35fURNdKTNNJYsWFnBv3Yk7VndDVIXKENS9kJb7byAuolhZpISM_lH9FEZuyXb8dv3zokJLuynDQm9URZ5EY9x1UeuA","eventSources":[{"alias":"myPush1","eventSource":"PushEventSource1","adapter":"PushAdapter"}]},"responseID":"11","responseTime":8024,"statusCode":200}*/
02-27 11:50:31.031: E/ViewRootImpl(30541): sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
02-27 11:50:31.066: E/myCSOLApp(30541): [http://9.127.62.227:10080/MYCSOL/apps/services/api/myCSOLApp/android/query] exception. TypeError: Cannot read property 'user' of null
02-27 11:50:31.081: D/CordovaLog(30541): Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'user' of null
02-27 11:50:31.081: E/Web Console(30541): Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'user' of null:1714
02-27 11:50:31.216: D/myCSOLApp(30541): response [http://9.127.62.227:10080/MYCSOL/apps/services/api/myCSOLApp/android/query] success: /*-secure-
02-27 11:50:31.216: D/myCSOLApp(30541): {"totalTime":8508,"isSuccessful":true,"requests":[{"isFav":"N","comments":[{"SEQNO":"1124","USERNAME":"EDGAR2 CAMARENA2テスト","COMMENTTYPE":"BP","REQUESTCOMMENT_ID":"20881","REQUESTID":"GASUK1402261124","COMMENTTEXT":"sdfsdf","UPDTIMESTAMP":"2014-02-26 14:47:40.002743","ANSWER":"","UPDUSERID":"ecamaren@mx1.ibm.com"}],"REQTYPE":"Accept maintenance contract","REQUESTID":"GASUK1402261124","TYPE":"TSSC","WWW_STATUS":"Submitted","UPDTIMESTAMP":""},{"isFav":"N","comments":[{"SEQNO":"1123","USERNAME":"EDGAR2 CAMARENA2テスト","COMMENTTYPE":"BP","REQUESTCOMMENT_ID":"20880","REQUESTID":"GASUK1402261123","COMMENTTEXT":"dfgdf","UPDTIMESTAMP":"2014-02-26 14:34:24.679642","ANSWER":"","UPDUSERID":"ecamaren@mx1.ibm.com"}],"REQTYPE":"Accept maintenance contract","REQUESTID":"GASUK1402261123","TYPE":"TSSC","WWW_STATUS":"Submitted","UPDTIMESTAMP":""}],"stat":"ok","responseHeaders":{"Server":"WebSphere Application Server\/8.5","X-Powered-By":"Servlet\/3.0","Transfer-Encoding":"chunked","Content-Language":"en-US","Content-Type":"application\/json","Date":"Thu, 27 Feb 2014 03:50:33 GMT"},"statusReason":"OK","responseID":"12","responseTime":8508,"statusCode":200}*/
02-27 11:50:31.271: E/myCSOLApp(30541): [http://9.127.62.227:10080/MYCSOL/apps/services/api/myCSOLApp/android/query] exception. TypeError: Cannot read property 'user' of null
02-27 11:50:31.286: D/CordovaLog(30541): Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'user' of null
02-27 11:50:31.286: E/Web Console(30541): Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'user' of null:1714
02-27 11:50:31.436: V/GCMBroadcastReceiver(30541): onReceive: com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION
02-27 11:50:31.436: V/GCMBroadcastReceiver(30541): GCM IntentService class: com.myCSOLApp.GCMIntentService
02-27 11:50:31.436: V/GCMBaseIntentService(30541): Acquiring wakelock
02-27 11:50:31.441: V/GCMBaseIntentService(30541): Intent service name: GCMIntentService-774173770625-2
02-27 11:50:31.446: D/GCMBaseIntentService(30541): handleRegistration: registrationId = APA91bGYP18rdbg_25Ginyts3qGmCPDMqLV4AEQARVEFSARyKyGexuKFIhuloZbg0tWzzq_35fURNdKTNNJYsWFnBv3Yk7VndDVIXKENS9kJb7byAuolhZpISM_lH9FEZuyXb8dv3zokJLuynDQm9URZ5EY9x1UeuA, error = null, unregistered = null
02-27 11:50:31.446: D/GCMRegistrar(30541): resetting backoff for com.myCSOLApp
02-27 11:50:31.446: V/GCMRegistrar(30541): Saving regId on app version 1
02-27 11:50:31.446: D/WLDroidGap(30541): Registered at the GCM server with registration id APA91bGYP18rdbg_25Ginyts3qGmCPDMqLV4AEQARVEFSARyKyGexuKFIhuloZbg0tWzzq_35fURNdKTNNJYsWFnBv3Yk7VndDVIXKENS9kJb7byAuolhZpISM_lH9FEZuyXb8dv3zokJLuynDQm9URZ5EY9x1UeuA
02-27 11:50:31.451: V/GCMBaseIntentService(30541): Releasing wakelock
02-27 11:50:31.451: D/CallbackProxy(30541): sendMessageToUiThreadSync Package=com.myCSOLApp message=112
02-27 11:50:31.491: D/TextLayoutCache(30541): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
02-27 11:50:31.491: D/TextLayoutCache(30541): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
02-27 11:50:31.491: D/TextLayoutCache(30541): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
02-27 11:50:31.516: D/TextLayoutCache(30541): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
02-27 11:50:31.516: D/TextLayoutCache(30541): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
02-27 11:50:31.521: D/TextLayoutCache(30541): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
```

I am trying it on a Samsung phone. The LogCat shows that all pending notifications have been dispatched. When I tried to call WL.Client.Push.*_*_hasPendings() it returns false. But when another new notification comes now when the app is in foreground the old notification shows up. So what could be the possible problem ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked it out by calling the android functions directly in my code.

```
if (WL.Client.Push){

    WL.Client.Push.onReadyToSubscribe = function(){
        alert("onReadyToSubscribe");

            alert("You said yes");
            WL.Client.Push.registerEventSourceCallback(
                    "myPush1", 
                    "PushAdapter", 
                    "PushEventSource1", 
                    pushNotificationReceived);

            if(!WL.Client.Push.isSubscribed("myPush1"))
                {
                    if(confirm('Do you allow CSOL to send notification to you?')) {
                        WL.Client.Push.subscribe("myPush1", {
                            onSuccess: doSubscribeSuccess,
                            onFailure: doSubscribeFailure
                        });
                }
                }
            else
                {
                    if(WL.Client.Push.__hasPendings()){
                    WL.Client.Push.__dispatchPendings();
                }
                cordova.exec(null, null, 'Push', 'dispatch', [ 'WL.Client.Push.__onmessage' ]);
                //cordova.exec("Push.dispatch", 'WL.Client.Push.__onmessage');
                }



    };

}
```